# How to make a text appear after printing a certain word in python

Tags: python

I've wanted to make a full text appear after I print a word in Python.

EX: Print the word “HELLO” → Text appear after saying “I'm a freaking begginer and wanted to learn how to code being a humanities scholar.”

Comment: actually, i was trying to writ a word and after that specific word is printed an text that i've written appeared after bellow the specific word, but i've only needed to print that word for the text to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to print two messages, one after the other, and the second isn't related to the first...

```
print("HELLO")
print("I'm a freaking begginer and wanted to learn how to code being a humanities scholar.")
```

If you wanted to make your second message relate to the first, you could try:

```
msg = "HELLO"
print(msg)

if (msg=="HELLO"):
    print("I'm a freaking begginer and wanted to learn how to code being a humanities scholar.")
```

The python command line doesn't 'respond' to what you print into it - unless you define a function and pass your message to it:

```py
    def response(msg):
        if (msg=="HELLO"):
            print("...")

-->response("HELLO")
-->...
```

Comment: i was trying to only write this word and text appeared after on the shell... Like write "word" and a full text appeared after.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to print the full text **after** you enter the word HELLO:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
if word == "HELLO":
    print ("I'm a freaking beginner and wanted to learn how to code being a humanities' scholar.")
else:
    print("You didn't enter the word HELLO, you entered the word", word)
```